# Deleting an object holding an event handler - it works fine, but how exactly and is this a good programming practice?

Tags: javascript, closures

So lets imagine this piece of JavaScript code:

```js
    class Foo{
        bar(){

            // This will work fine.
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log('Bum!')
            },1000)
        }
    }
    let holdMe = {
        foo: new Foo(),
    }
    holdMe.foo.bar();

    // Even when I delete it immediately.
    delete holdMe.foo;
```

As you can see, I am deleting the 'foo' object, instance of Foo, **before** the timeout handler can work.

In the past (having experience in other languages) I would do rather something like this:

```js
    class Foo{
        // We take a callback handler, which we'll call, when we're done.
        bar(onFinished){
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log('Bum!');
                onFinished();
            },1000)
        }
    }
    let holdMe = {
        foo: new Foo(),
    }
    holdMe.foo.bar(()=>{
        // Now we can delete it.
        delete holdMe.foo;
    });
```

So I would make sure the 'parent scope' actually can delete the object.

My first question is - am I right, that this works because of how Closures work in JavaScript, and not because its garbage collector is so lazy?

The second question is - OK, assuming this is how it works, and it will work fine, but is this a good programming practice (in JS?).

And the last one - how the engine actually knows to not "really" delete this Foo instance? I mean it deletes the reference in `holdMe` but apparently doesn't remove it completely from memory, but why? How does it "know" there is a handler inside? I just called some function (setTimeout) with a reference to some anonymous callback function.

The engine knows that the callback is defined in the "Foo" instance and it's so smart to keep it?

Sorry for more than one question, but I believe it's better than spamming SO with three related ones :)

Comment: `delete` doesn't delete objects. It just removes variables or properties that hold references to the object. The object doesn't go away if there are other references. A timer created with `setTimeout` is referenced by the event queue.

Comment: `As you can see, I am deleting the 'foo' object, instance of Foo, before the timeout handler can work.` but not before setTimeout is called, and the reference to the timeout handler is created.

Comment: @Barmar & James - thank you very much, I understand the the answer to my second question (is this a good programming practice) the answer is yes:) Thanks again!